# Send email from lumen

Tags: laravel, email, lumen

I am using `vue.js` as my front end and Lumen as my api service. Now I need to send emails from lumen. This is what i did for this.

.env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=********@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=******@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Sample Email App
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and then edited the file `bootstrap\app.php` and uncommented the following lines.

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->withFacades();
Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');
$app->withEloquent();
```

In the controller, I have used the following code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

private function sendActivationEmail( $email = null ){
        $email_sent = false;
        if( $email != null ){ 
            // send email
            Mail::raw('Raw string email', function($msg) { 
                $msg->to(['tismon@gmail.com']); $msg->from(['x@x.com']); 
            });

        }
        return $email_sent;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Register `MailServiceProvider` in bootstrap/app.php file

```
$app->register(\Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
$app->configure('mail');
```

try adding below code to AppServiceProvider.php within register function

```
$this->app->singleton('mailer', function ($app) {
            $app->configure('services');
            return $app->loadComponent('mail', 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider', 'mailer');
        });
```

if not working After the above configuration, try Mail send function

```
Mail::send('user.emails.registration' , $data, function($msg) use ($to,$from,$subject)
                {
                    $msg->to($to)->from($from)->subject($subject);
                });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not working... 
`[2017-10-20 18:55:25] lumen.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider' not found in /api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php:164
Stack trace:
#0 /api/bootstrap/app.php(267): Laravel\Lumen\Application->register('Illuminate\\Mail...')`